# simple_form not showing nested field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-attributes

I am trying simple_form nested attributes as suggested in https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models

The thing is, when I render the form I just can see the submit button, but not the input field. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Screen with input field missing]

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @incident] do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :comments do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.input :info, label: "Informe de seguimiento" %>
  <% end %>


  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit "Enviar", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**incidents_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::IncidentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_incident, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  def index
    @incidents = Incident.all
  end
  def show

  end
  def new
    @incident = Incident.new
    @incident.comments.build
  end
  def edit

  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @incident.update(incident_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @incident, notice: 'Incidencia actualizada actualizada con éxito.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @incident }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @incident.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def set_incident
    @incident = Incident.find(params[:id])
  end

  def incident_params
    params.require(:incident).permit(:info, :subject, :status, comments_attributes: [:info])
  end

end
```

**incident.rb**

```
class Incident < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['info'].blank? }

  enum status: [:abierto, :tramite, :pendiente, :cerrado]
  after_initialize :set_default_status, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_status
    self.status ||= :abierto
  end
end
```

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  belongs_to :incident
end
```

Comment: Maybe this is not the case, but try `simple_form_for @incident do |f|`  Seems there is missing the `:id` and , `:_destroy` in `comments_attributes`: `comments_attributes: [:id, :info, :_destroy]`.  Also, Now I see the page url is it incidents/show.html.erb? The method `show` in controller is empty, maybe you deleted something from the post? If you are using that controller try move there the building of the nested field.

Comment: What screen are we looking at here? The path `/admin/incidents/2` suggests the `Admin::Incidents` `show` or a submitted `edit` with an error thus being the `update` action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `@incident.comments.build` to the show action of Admin::IncidentsController. Now it has no comments, I suppose, so the form is empty.

And you need to add `:id` to `comments_attributes`, without it comment can't be saved. If you planning to have some 'Delete' checkbox for existing comments you also need to add `:_destroy` to the attributes array

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I just didn't used  build in a place other than new or create

Comment: One question: Following this schema, how could i validate the presence of info in comment model from incident show action? The thing is that the form is send, and the incident attributes updates with no error message, despite of having the validation in comment model

Comment: @JuanseCora, try to remove `reject_if` option from `accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments`